# How enable hardware acceleration in vlcj?

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I don't find how enable hardware acceleration in [vlcj](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj). Is it possible? I found parameter --ffmpeg-hw, but i don't know how use it.

Answer (score 0):

That flag is not present in VLC 2.2.x so is likely redundant. I think that hardware acceleration is now enabled by default.

That flag was present in earlier versions of VLC, e.g. 2.0.x.

To use flags like that with vlcj you pass the arguments to the MediaPlayerFactory constructor.

```
MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--ffmpeg-hw");
```

Then use that factory to create your media player.

vlcj knows nothing about hardware acceleration, and does nothing with that parameter except pass it directly to LibVLC.